How to sort an array of strings with different length properly
I have a question about sorting with C#. I want to implement a function to sort an array of strings such as ["AA", "A", "Z", "ZZZ"] alphabetically without any built-in sort methods. I have tried some Compare function and my logic which is comparison between each character of the two strings, but it does not work properly.
if you compare two strings with the same length like "A" and "Z", this works fine. The problem is that "Z" comes before "AAA" because it is a shorter string.
That would be appreciated if you could help me out. Thank you.
for (int i = 0; i < copy_database.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < copy_database.Length - 1 - i; j++)
    {
        if (copy_database[j].Value != null && copy_database[j + 1].Value != null)
        {
            int k = 0;

            while (k < Math.Min(copy_database[j].Value.Title.Length, copy_database[j + 1].Value.Title.Length) &&
                   copy_database[j].Value.Title[k] == copy_database[j + 1].Value.Title[k])
            {
                k++;
            }

            if (k < Math.Min(copy_database[j].Value.Title.Length, copy_database[j + 1].Value.Title.Length))
            {
                if (copy_database[j].Value.Title[k] < copy_database[j + 1].Value.Title[k])
                {
                    // Swap elements
                    Key_Value_Pair temp = copy_database[j];
                    copy_database[j] = copy_database[j + 1];
                    copy_database[j + 1] = temp;
                    break;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 break;
             }



Please, don't cram everything into a single routine, extract methods. Here we have

Compare Strings
Sort arrays

Let's first compare strings:
private static int CompareStrings(string left, string right) {
  if (left is null) 
    return right is null ? 0 : -1;
  
  if (right is null) 
    return +1;

  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length); ++i) 
    if (left[i] < right[i])
      return -1;
    else if (left[i] > right[i])
      return +1;
  
  return left.Length < right.Length ? -1 
       : left.Length > right.Length ? +1 
       : 0;
}

Then sort array
private static void SortArray<T>(T[] array, Func<T, T, int> sort) {
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(array);
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sort);

  for (bool hasWork = true; hasWork;) {
    hasWork = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; ++i) {
      if (sort(array[i], array[i + 1]) > 0) {
        hasWork = true;

        (array[i], array[i + 1]) = (array[i + 1], array[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

Finally, we can put
SortArray(copy_database, CompareStrings);


It perfectly worked. I learned a lot from you answer! Thank you.
